# osmdroid onScroll question

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using a mapListener in osmDroid, and it works great.
the problem is:
I also have a locationListener that changes the center of the map when a location change
is received,
 So the onScroll function is called both when a location change occurs and
when the user scrolls the map.
 I want to be able to identify which is which in the onScroll.
So far i couldn't find a solution. does any one have an idea?
Thanks in advance
Omri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely using `onLocationChanged (Location location)` to identify when the location has been changed and set the centre of the map. So why not call something in that same function? Then you will know whether or not you are calling the `onScroll()` method or not.

If you provide your code, then perhaps I can be more helpful.